# Putting a CircularProgressIndicator below each image

Tags: flutter

There are a lot of such stack elements on the page:

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
        child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
      Center(child: _getImage(imagePath)),
    ],
),
```

So there will be a CircularProgressIndicator below each image. Does it reduce the ui speed? When the Progress Indicator widget is ovelapped by the other widget will be disabled then?

Answer (score 1):

First off you may use `const` on the constructor for better performance. Secondly, if you want to show a progress indicator when the image is loading maybe try using a `FutureBuilder` to check if the image is loading, if so return a CircularProgressIndicator else return the image.

But generally speaking flutter should be able to render tons of CircularProgressIndicator and yes it will still render the CircularProgressIndicator  even if your image is shown and will therefore take up resources. If you dont want it to show and take resources you could warap it in a `Visablity` widget but I highly recommend using a futurebuilder so you can maintain the state of the image loading.

Comment: here, https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images , they show the same approach for a single image

Comment: Well a few reason on why they did that. Number one is that its only one image so it wont really matter. Number two is because they are using a widget that does the fetching of the image in the widget it self so using `FutureBuilder` here is not possible. What you can do is create your own fadein image widget by using `AnimatedOpcaity` and `FutureBuilder` if you want. Im sure there are alos other alternative packages to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using progress loaders for image loading state, but I'd go with a package.

[extended_image: ^4.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image) seems like a good one and check the code below. It allows you to interfere in Loading State of the image, and you can put whatever widget in place of that state. This package does more than your intended use as well.

```
ExtendedImage.network(
  url,
  width: ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(600),
  height: ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(400),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
  cache: true,
  loadStateChanged: (ExtendedImageState state) {
    switch (state.extendedImageLoadState) {
      case LoadState.loading:
        _controller.reset();
        return Image.asset(
          "assets/loading.gif",
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        );
        break;

      ///if you don't want override completed widget
      ///please return null or state.completedWidget
      //return null;
      //return state.completedWidget;
      case LoadState.completed:
        _controller.forward();
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: _controller,
          child: ExtendedRawImage(
            image: state.extendedImageInfo?.image,
            width: ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(600),
            height: ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(400),
          ),
        );
        break;
      case LoadState.failed:
        _controller.reset();
        return GestureDetector(
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                "assets/failed.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: Text(
                  "load image failed, click to reload",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          onTap: () {
            state.reLoadImage();
          },
        );
        break;
    }
  },
)
```